# Type Guard unrecognized by compiler

Tags: typescript

In this example here the Typescript compiler still complains, even though in my opinion it shouldn't

```
type Car = {
  isOn: boolean
  name: string
}


function doSomething(key: keyof Car, value: string | boolean) {
  const car: Car = {
    isOn: false,
    name: "myCar",
  }
  if (typeof car[key] === typeof value) {
    car[key] = value
  }
}
```

Error Message:

"TS2322: Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please edit to include the error as text and not a screenshot?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2):

The type of the result cannot be inferred properly. to do this, you need to template it:

```
function doSomething<K extends keyof Car>(key: K, value: Car[K]) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes!
That solved it! Thank you very much
Do you know why keyof Car doesn't infer the type correctly?

Comment: the `key` and `value` types are not linked in your code, and the compiler doesn't care about manual typechecks with `typeof` (wich makes sense, because for example `typeof []` is `"object"`), so the compiler only trusts the type that you give to it.

Comment: btw, you can also drop that manual type check